# replacing the `'` char using awk

Tags: awk, gsub

I have lines with a single `:` and a`'` in them that I want to get rid of. I want to use `awk` for this. I've tried using:

```
 awk '{gsub ( "[:\\']","" ) ; print $0 }'
```

and

```
 awk '{gsub ( "[:\']","" ) ; print $0 }'
```

and

```
 awk '{gsub ( "[:']","" ) ; print $0 }'
```

non of them worked, but return the error `Unmatched ".`. when I put

```
 awk '{gsub ( "[:_]","" ) ; print $0 }'
```

then It works and removes all `:` and `_` chars. How can I get rid of the `'` char?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use:

1. Octal code for the single quote:

   ```
   [:\47]
   ```
2. The single quote inside double quotes, but in that case special
   characters will be expanded by the shell:

   ```
   % print a\': | awk "sub(/[:']/, x)"        
   a
   ```
3. Use a dynamic regexp, but there are performance implications related
   to this approach:

   ```
   % print a\': | awk -vrx="[:\\\']" 'sub(rx, x)'  
   a
   ```

Answer (score 14):

`tr` is made for this purpose

```
echo test\'\'\'\':::string | tr -d \':
teststring

$ echo test\'\'\'\':::string | awk '{gsub(/[:\47]*/,"");print $0}'
teststring
```

Answer (score 10):

This works:

```
awk '{gsub( "[:'\'']","" ); print}'
```

Answer (score 6):

With bash you cannot insert a single quote inside a literal surrounded with single quotes. Use `'"'"'` for example.

First `'` closes the current literal, then `"'"` concatenates it with a literal containing only a single quote, and `'` reopens a string literal, which will be also concatenated.

What you want is:

```
awk '{gsub ( "[:'"'"']","" ) ; print $0; }'
```

ssapkota's alternative is also good (`'\''`).

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why you are restricting yourself to using awk, anyways you've got many answers from other users. You can also use sed to get rid of " :' "

```
sed 's/:\'//g'
```

This will also serve your purpose. Simple and less complex.

Answer (score 3):

This also works:

`awk '{gsub("\x27",""); print}'`

Comment: I've heard that hex characters tend to be very different between various implementations of awk. See [here](http://awk.freeshell.org/Frequently_Asked_Questions#toc14). Better on some implementations to use octal numbers, such as `"\047"`.

Comment: To clarify my previous comment: hex chars can behave differently in certain circumstances. For example `print "\x27foo\x27"` will work with mawk and busybox awk, but not gawk.

Answer (score 1):

simplest
 `awk '{gsub(/\047|:/,"")};1'`