# Remove a specific character using awk or sed

Tags: linux, awk, sed, replace

I have a command output from which I want to remove the double quotes `"`.

Command:

```sh
strings -a libAddressDoctor5.so |\
grep EngineVersion |\
awk '{if(NR==2)print}' |\
awk '{print$2}'
```

Output:

```
EngineVersion="5.2.5.624"
```

I'd like to know how to remove unwanted characters with `awk` or `sed`.

Comment: `sed 's/"//g'` - removes all `"`

Comment: @Banthar: Thanks, what does `s` means here?

Comment: The `s` means 'substitute'. Reading `'s/"//g'` from left to right, it says to substitute " with nothing, and do so for every " in the input.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Use sed's substitution: `sed 's/"//g'`

`s/X/Y/` replaces X with Y.

`g` means all occurrences should be replaced, not just the first one.

Answer (score 47):

Using just awk you could do (I also shortened some of your piping):

```
strings -a libAddressDoctor5.so | awk '/EngineVersion/ { if(NR==2) { gsub("\"",""); print $2 } }'
```

I can't verify it for you because I don't know your exact input, but the following works:

```
echo "Blah EngineVersion=\"123\"" | awk '/EngineVersion/ { gsub("\"",""); print $2 }'
```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520816/replacing-the-char-using-awk) on removing single quotes.

Comment: Awk's `gsub` function is what I needed to remove characters directly from a awk script, not the command line, thank you.

Answer (score 21):

[`tr`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tr) can be more concise for removing characters than `sed` or `awk`, especially when you want to remove multiple different characters from a string.

Removing double quotes:

```sh
echo '"Hi"' | tr -d \"
# Prints Hi without quotes
```

Removing different kinds of brackets:

```sh
echo '[{Hi}]' | tr -d {}[]
# Prints Hi without brackets
```

`-d` stands for "delete".

Comment: The best (alternative) option even if not the option the OP (Original Poster) asked for.