# How to remove 'www.' with awk in output file

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk

How can I remove all the 'www.' with awk in my output file.

e.g.: my output file has multiple sites like

```
abc.com 
www.def.com 
blabla.org 
www.zxc.net
```

I would like to remove all the `www.` in my output file:

```
abc.com 
def.com 
blabla.org 
zxc.net
```

Comment: Why "with awk"?

Comment: BTW, this is a subset of the space covered in [BashFAQ #21](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/021)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove unwanted character using awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8008546/remove-unwanted-character-using-awk)

Comment: What would you want to happen if one of the lines in your output file was just `www.org` (one alias for the W3C home page)?

Answer (score 1):

Probably better done in `sed`:

```
 sed -i 's/^www\.//g' outputFile
```

In awk:

```
 awk '{gsub(/^www\./,"",$0)}1' outputFile
```

Comment: Probably better to use `sed -i 's/^www\.//g' outputFile` to avoid cases like `thisisawww.net`.

Comment: @Defenestrator Good idea. I've updated both `sed` and `awk` with the `^`

Comment: get rid of the `g` from both commands. You can't remove from the front of a string more than once. You also don't need the `,$0` in the awk command as that's the default.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you're looking for:

```
$ cat file
abc.com
www.def.com
blabla.org
www.zxc.net
www.org
www.acl.lanl.gov

$ sed -E 's/^www\.(([^.]+(\.|$)){2,})/\1/' file
abc.com
def.com
blabla.org
zxc.net
www.org
acl.lanl.gov
```

The above uses a sed that has `-E` for ERE support, e.g. GNU or OSX sed. Note the need for a more comprehensive input file to test if a proposed solution really works or not.