# Convert a list of IPs (with single quotes) to comma delimited

Tags: awk

How can i write the script using `awk` to convert a string of `IP`s like this into comma seperated. I have around 70K IPs.

```
Current format - '114.124.35.252' '114.79.61.186' '39.225.242.17' '202.62.16.29'

Desired format - '114.124.35.252','114.79.61.186','39.225.242.17','202.62.16.29'
```

Comment: See [this][1] post. Sounds about the same.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520816/replacing-the-char-using-awk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just replace the `space` with `,` using `sed` if there are no other contents with space in the file. Else, edit your question with more details.

```
sed 's/ /,/g' File
```

If it is not file content, use this:

```
sed 's/ /,/g' <<< $string     #string is the variable with the IP string
```

**EDIT:**

```
AMD$ cat File
'114.124.35.252'
'114.79.61.186'
'39.225.242.17'
'202.62.16.29'
```

1.You can use `tr` (this will replace the last newline with `,` as well. See `man tr` for details)

```
AMD$ tr '\n', ',' < File
'114.124.35.252','114.79.61.186','39.225.242.17','202.62.16.29',
```

2.Else, you can use this `awk` command:

```
AMD$ awk -v n=$(wc -l < File) '{if(NR!=n){ORS=","}else{ORS="\n"}}1' File
'114.124.35.252','114.79.61.186','39.225.242.17','202.62.16.29'
```

The default record seperator for `awk` is `'\n'`. Change this to `,` for all but the last line.

Comment: Thanks All for your answers.

Comment: Thanks All for your answers. The list of IPs in the text file is not formatted with a space (Stackoverflow reconstructed it to rows when i listed in the original format). The original list is all listed with a line break like this<br/>  '114.124.35.252'<br/> '114.79.61.186' <br/>'39.225.242.17'<br/> '202.62.16.29'

Comment: Sharing a link on how the original list looks like - https://www.dropbox.com/s/u0q8b1wtw65e7qy/ip.txt?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$ awk -F- '{gsub("\047 ","\047,",$2)}1' OFS="-" file
Current format - '114.124.35.252','114.79.61.186','39.225.242.17','202.62.16.29'
```

Answer (score 0):

Idiomatic awk:

```
$ awk -v OFS=, '{$1=$1}1' ip.txt
'114.124.35.252','114.79.61.186','39.225.242.17','202.62.16.29'
```

> $1=$1

Reconstitutes the input line replacing the default white-space separator with the new output file separator defined by `-v OFS=,`

> 1

Is a "true" pattern, triggering the default action, which is to print the (now reconstituted) line.